# sum of hours and minutes which is in Date time datatype in sql server

Tags: sql-server

How do I sum the time?  Here is the SQL I have a problem with:

```
drop table #temp
Create TABLE #Temp (EmpID varchar(50),Inout varchar(50),Punchdate datetime2(0),rowid int, INTotal datetime ,Outtotal datetime)
declare @ttt int
--truncate table @Temp
--drop table @temp
;WITH timediff AS

(    select ID,  In_out,Punch_Date ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Punch_date) AS [row]
        -- Create an index number ordered by time.                
        from tblCAPdata tbl  
        where ID='00007971' and In_Out!='Null Mode' and CONVERT(date,Punch_Date)=CONVERT(date,'2015-12-30 00:00:00')

)

insert Into #Temp
select *,
 convert(varchar(8),dateadd(mi, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                      (SELECT other.Punch_Date 
                              FROM timediff Other 
                              WHERE other.[row] = timediff.[row]-1 and In_Out='In' and In_Out!='Out'  ), 
                       timediff.Punch_Date),0),0),108)
                 AS INTimedifferance,
              -- convert(varchar(8),dateadd(mi,datediff(Minute, day_start, day_end),0),108)
     CONVERT(varchar(8),dateadd(mi, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                      (SELECT other.Punch_Date 
                              FROM timediff Other 
                              WHERE other.[row] = timediff.[row]-1 and In_Out='Out' and In_Out!='In' ), 
                       timediff.Punch_Date),0),0),108) AS OUTTimedifferance


FROM timediff 
where NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   timediff omit
    WHERE  omit.In_Out = timediff.In_Out
    AND    omit.[row]   = timediff.[row] - 1
    );
select sum(INTotal) as v,sum(OuttotAL) from #Temp
```

The error message is:

```
Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
Operand data type datetime is invalid for sum operator.
```

PFA.[image: in that am getting in time and out time .]

I need to take sum of In time and Out time which is in Date time type

Comment: Why would you use INTtotal as datetime? Shouldnt it be int?

Comment: because that is time format like HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach links the In and Out times to a single row for each employee IN punch, calculates the number of hours, then lets the last expression perform your desired calculation.

```
WITH TimesWithIds AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, In_Out ORDER BY Punch_Date) AS RowNum
    FROM [Table] T1
), InAndOuts (
    SELECT
        InTimes.ID,
        InTimes.Punch_Date AS PunchIn,
        OutTimes.Punch_Date AS PuchOut,
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,4), DATEDIFF(SS, InTimes.Punch_Date, OutTimes.PunchDate))/3600 AS PunchHours -- Be sure this is large enough for you
    FROM TimesWithIds InTimes
        INNER JOIN TimesWithIds OutTimes
            ON InTimes.RowNum = OutTimes.RowNum
                AND InTimes.ID = OutTimes.ID
    WHERE InTimes.In_Out = 'In'
        AND OutTimes.In_Out = 'Out'
)
    SELECT
        ID,
        SUM(PunchHours) AS PunchHours
    FROM InAndOuts
    GROUP BY
        ID
```

The example above calculates a decimal form of total hours by each employee. Add any filters and use your desired data format. Keep in mind you can't store the total hours as a true date/time - has to be some numeric type since after 24 hours, a TIME datatype would just reset.

Comment: hi, that is not what i expected. i need to take in and out details then i need to calculate sum of in time hours and sum of out time hours, plz help me. i strucked with this for past two days
PFA for my question

Comment: As comments and answers have stated, you can't store a difference of 2 times as a time. You have to use a numeric type. Otherwise, the time datatype will overflow after the the hours is more than 23 hours. No `SUM` aggregate can work on a date data type, and you'll notice any `DATE_DIFF` will always return numeric for these reasons no matter what unit of measure of time you select.

Comment: jason, seriously i dont understand what you are saying, plz help me. Is i need to take seconds in DATEDIFF instead of minutes?

Comment: DATEDIFF is just returning a number is all i'm saying. Whether you do minutes or seconds is up to you - just keep that unit of measure in mind to convert to hours or whatever total you need. You can SUM the output of DATEDIFF, but you can't put it back into the DATETIME datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to seconds (using DATEDIFF) or some other time unit, then sum.  Then you can convert back to datetime if you need to.

Comment: Thank you david.could u tell me the below query is right or wrong? CONVERT(varchar(8),dateadd(mi, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                      (SELECT other.Punch_Date 
                              FROM timediff Other 
                              WHERE other.[row] = timediff.[row]-1 and In_Out='Out' and In_Out!='In' ), 
                       timediff.Punch_Date),0),0),108) AS OUTTimedifferance

Comment: This isnt actual answer. It suppose to be comment.

Comment: i am a fresher, if u dont mind could u tell me clearly

Comment: @Denn there wasn't an actual question!